# iOS 6/7 20px difference using autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode-storyboard

I've got a background for the project that I am working on, which includes a 20px coloured bar for the top of an iOS 7 device.

This worked fine without autolayout, setting a 20px delta in storyboard. But now I can't do that, and I am stuck with constraints - which I cannot set on a per-OS basis.

Whatever I do, I seem to end up with the version on iOS 7 being 20px higher than on ios 6... Something I need to rectify, as I also have a bar under that status bar which is coloured for a navigation controller.

I've attached the background image - if I need to modify it to work with autolayout, I'm happy to do that.

[image: Background image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a "top layout guide" object in your view hierarchy. If you build vertical constraints based on that, they pin to the top of the window if there is no status bar, or under the status bar otherwise. Use that.